# get path from <input type="file"/>

Tags: file, input, fonts, openfiledialog

I am using

```
    <input type="file" id="uploadFont" value="Upload Font"/>
```

to upload a font to my application. The open file dialog opens up and I choose the font.

How can I get the path of the choosen font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is browser-dependant, but on modern secure browsers you can't - and this is a good thing. If you were able to read this path, an attacker would also be able to, which is a huge information leak - for example it mostly gives him your username, if you chose a file from e.g. "My Documents" or your home directory.

If you describe, what you need this path for, we might be able to help you conceive a workaround, but from the POV of your browser, this is just "some file", without the notion of its location in the underlying OS file tree.

Comment: Very good point thanks...I need the path so I can update the src in the @font-face css side.

Comment: You should re-publish the file on your website (in a protected way) and make the CSS point to this URL. On first load, this will really request the file, but it will end up in the cache, providing fast access on subsequent loads.

Comment: You might be able to get the **name** (not the **path**) on the server side, if the browser choses to transmit it, but I would just generate a file name and republish using it. There is the trick to load the font into a hidden <img> tag (which ofcourse fails) to accelerate caching it.