# File input what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, file, input

I've been working on this form for a while trying to get a text field to mimic a file input field (when clicked it triggers the hidden file field to open). I have used a bit of Javascript to change the VALUE of the text field but I can't get it to work. See it here http://jsfiddle.net/ygMLm/.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function getFile(){
   document.getElementById("uploaded").click();
 }
 function sub(obj){
    var file = obj.value;
    var fileName = file.split("\\");
    document.getElementById("upclicked").value = fileName[fileName.length-1];
    document.adupload.submit();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
</script>

<p><input type="text" id="upclicked" onclick="getFile()" placeholder="Select a File (960 Width JPEG)"></p>
<div style='height: 0px;width: 0px; overflow:hidden;'>
<input type="file" name="date" value="" id="uploaded" onclick="getFile()">
```

EDIT:

```
$('#uploaded').change(function(){
    var file = obj.value;
    var fileName = file.split("\\");

    $('input[name=faux]').val(fileName[fileName.length-1]);
});
```

Comment: Which browser?  I just tried with Chrome and at first glance it seems to do what you want...EDIT: sorry--now I see what you are complaining about...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802881/get-path-from-input-type-file

Comment: @Diodeus - Is there an alternative method?

Comment: @EfrainAnthonyNegron unfortunately you won't be able to trigger a click of `input[type=file]` on most browsers. What you can do is position your `invisible` file type element over the text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your jQuery code to run on DOM ready:

```
$("#uploaded").change(
  function() {
    var fullPath = $(this).val();
    var splitPath = fullPath.split("\\");
    $("#upclicked").val(splitPath[splitPath.length - 1]);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following post

[how to fire event on file select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942821/how-to-fire-event-on-file-select)

for examples of how to use the `change()` event on the `file` control.  You should be place your code to update the value of the textbox, inside of this event.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not the greatest in javascript so this isn't apparent enough for me to completely grasp. I've tried the code above in the EDIT section.